# Is it necessary to assign null to a temp string value after using it?

Tags: c++, string

Say I have a snippet of code like this:

```
else if (array[z] == 1){
                string buf = string("00010");
                barzip += buf;
                string buf = string(NULL);

            }
```

Is it redundant to assign NULL to buf since I am going to reuse the string variable in the next `else if` statement? Thanks!

Comment: It's not only redundant, but not allowed per `std::string`'s contract, not to mention illegal since `buf` was already declared. `NULL` (or better, `nullptr`) is for pointers.

Comment: @chris That's what I assumed, but just wanted to make sure. Thanks

Comment: `string(NULL)` actually causes undefined behaviour. An empty string is `string()` or `string("")`. And the easiest way to clear a string is `buf.clear();`

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant.  In fact, the string `buf` will go out of scope at the end of the block, so the `buf` destructor will be called.

```
else if (array[z] == 1)
{
  string buf = string("00010");
  barzip += buf;
  buf = string(NULL);  // second declaration would not compile.    
}
```

Should just be

```
else if (array[z] == 1)
{
  string buf("00010");
  barzip += buf;
  // buf goes out of scope here; destructor is called. 
  // Each iteration through the block will use a newly-constructed buf variable
}
```

Comment: even better, `barzip += string("00010");`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to do that. The scope of the variable buf is only in that else branch of the if statement.  If that code isn't run, then buf is never created.  Also, if that same code is run in a loop it's a new buf every time since once you leave the else if branch there, buf is forgotten.

note also that you can do this:

```
string buf("00010");
```

Instead of:

```
string buf = string("00010");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
string buf = string("00010");
barzip += buf;
string buf = string(NULL);
```

will not compile, because you are trying to declare two variables with the same name (`buf`) in the same block.

Second, you are not *assigning* `NULL` anywhere. You are *initialising* an unnamed temporary string with `NULL`. This is **undefined behaviour**, which means anything can happen when the program runs.

If you are lucky, it will crash immediately to show you that there is an error in your code. If you are not lucky, it will not crash and don't do anything harmful for the first 20 times you execute the program, and crash at the 21st attempt, leading to an endless bug hunt.

After the illegal initialisation, you technically do assign `buf` that unnamed temporary string, but as the behaviour is already undefined at that point, it's meaningless to reason about it any further.

It seems you have a C background and are used to the manual handling of `char` pointers. In C++, it's better to conceptually treat `std::string` objects exactly like built-in non-pointer types. Do you "clear" an `int` when it's no longer used? You don't, of course. Do you "clear" a `double` before assigning it a new value? Again, you don't. So don't try such things with `std::string`, either. It just doesn't make sense.